# Multiple Column Encoding in Python

Tags: python, encoding, dataset

#### Hi everyone,

I have a dataset which has 4 columns:

*Language_name, Speaking, Reading, Writing*

LANG_NAME   READING WRITING

English 4   4

German  6   6

French  3   3

I want to encode them in that fashion :

eng_speaking eng_reading german_speaking german_reading french_speaking french_speaking

4 4 0 0 0 0

0 0 6 6 0 0

0 0 0 0 3 3

I couldn't find what I needed exactly on the posts.

Comment: Are you using pandas?

Comment: Yes, I am using pandas. But with get_dummies method, I couldn't make it.